# Learning to write philosophy

Tags: terminology

How does one learn to write philosophy? I don't mean the wording but how to construct the text and perhaps pull in conclusions drawn by others. Thank you in advance for your insights.

P.S: Not sure what tags I can put on this question.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me exactly what is meant by "writing philosophy" as opposed to writing almost any other persuasive essay. Virtually all effective writing requires creating sound arguments by developing a thesis and providing good support for the thesis, perhaps highlighting flaws with other viewpoints, citing sources as required, etc. Learn to examine texts critically, read a lot, and you'll be surprised how easy it comes. :)

Comment: Can you unpack this a bit further for us? @stoicfury's question highlights the real problem -- is there any chance you might be able to specify what you might intend by "writing philosophy" as distinct from any other formal writing?

Comment: @JosephWeissman apologies for waiting 4 years to answer :) . I was unclear about the subject at the time and was just wondering if there any conventions and methodology in the genre. Stoicfury has given some leads so I'll look into those.

Answer (score 2):

> How does one learn to write philosophy?

Undergraduate philosophy classes are the best starting point.  Try to find an institution of higher learning in your general vicinity, and sign up for a class.

Comment: I've had my fill of studies so if there are alternatives I'm willing to put in effort :)